# appending special characters to file path

Tags: c#

I am trying to open and display the contents of a file. The file path is being created using the Windows explorer dialog box, this gets placed in a text `File_Path_TB` and has the format `C:\Users\User\Desktop\testDoc.txt`. I would like to use this file path held in `File_Path_TB` to open and display the contents of the document. 
 The desired output string is as follows `@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\testDoc.txt"` . 
 My code is as follows

```
private void Load_File_Contents_BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      string FilePath = File_Path_TB.ToString();
      string File_Contents = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
      MessageBox.Show(File_Contents);
}
```

I have tried the following; 
`string File_Contents = File.ReadAllText("@"" + filepath + """);`

any suggestions and help would be appreciated!

Comment: Simply `File.ReadAllText(File_Path_TB)` ? If that fails please describe what happens.  The `@""` is only for you to use when your write strings in your own code, you never decorate a variable with it, slashes that are already within a variable are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `ReadAllText` needs:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\testDoc.txt
```

not

```
@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\testDoc.txt"
```

The decorations `@"` and `"` belong to the C# syntax and enclose verbatim strings. They are not part of the string value but are only delimiters! `filepath` already contains the the right value. Don't add it anything.

```
string FilePath = File_Path_TB.Text;
string File_Contents = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
...
```

Is all you need to do.

---

If you want to assign the path as string constant in C#, then you have to write

```
string FilePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\testDoc.txt";
```

The contents of `FilePath` after this assignement is

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\testDoc.txt
```

Comment: great, that's good to know that when using a string as the file path the `@".."` is not needed. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
string FilePath = File_Path_TB.Text;
```

To access the Text property of the TextBox.

So you code could be:

```
private void Load_File_Contents_BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      string FilePath = File_Path_TB.Text;
      string File_Contents = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
      MessageBox.Show(File_Contents);
}
```

Comment: It Works. But can be simplified, I did not notice that, I just wanted to show that he wanted to access the Text property, not the TextBox object ToString method. I edited my answer.

Comment: _"It Works. But can be simplified"_ - very true.  Downvote removed and +1 in place :)